# Is there HTML tag creation shortcut in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm wondering if there is any keyboard shortcut that allows you to create HTML tags fast..

For example, if I want to create something like this

```
<div><ul class="short"><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li></ul></div>
```

Can I write something like **div>ul.short>li*5{*}** and hit a shortcut key to have the tags above created for me?

thanks!

Comment: You could record a macro, record your steps, and play that back from a shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question... but the tool is only available for VS 2012 and 2013, not 2010.

The functionality I described can be found in a software called **Emmet**:

http://emmet.io/

Emmet for VS (intro):

http://devproconnections.com/web-development/simplify-html-coding-emmet-visual-studio

Emmet download for VS 2013:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/427e078e-4885-424b-8667-6485b7937145

Answer (score 5):

You can download an extension for Visual Studios called "Web Essentials". It's a highly recommended extension for anyone doing web development and provides LOADS of easy helper functionality.  For your particular question, it has something called Zen Coding. Here's a Blog describing the benefits and use:

http://dannydnet.blogspot.com/2013/12/vs2013-web-essentials-zen-coding-is.html

Here is a link to the list of other features that may be helpful to you as well:
http://vswebessentials.com/features/html

Comment: Note: Zen Coding was renamed to Emmet sometime ago.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to an answer.

You could record a macro, record your steps, and play that back from a shortcut.

After I typed that, I went and did some research and testing, and there is indeed a pretty good set of tools for creating, saving, running, and managing macros.  Just do a quick Google search.  It will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Yes, a macro would solve this particular scenario but I believe that he's looking for a Zen Coding solution such as Emmet which is built into VS or Web Essentials which is a popular extension that adds Zen Coding features.

Answer (score 0):

write html and select html 5 drop down menu.
All codes will appear on the visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

visual studio code automatically makes this. It is called emmett
type div>ul.short>li*5  and click TAB
and below code will appear

```
<div>
        <ul class="short">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```